# Creating a Hybrid USB drive

Tags: usb, usb-storage

1/ Is it possible to create a hybrid USB drive?  Needs to be functionally the same as a hybrid CD : Mac sees **only** mac partition, windows sees **only** windows partition... bonus if they can share files between partitions just like a hybrid CD can.

2/ I have an .iso of a hybrid CD.  Is it possible to 'dump' this image onto a USB drive somehow ... and obviously make a hybrid USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I can think of that would somewhat fit your description is to partition the drive so that one partition is an HFS+ partition and the other is NTFS. Both of them are viewable only from Mac OSX and Windows, respectively.

I would guess the reason nobody thought of making this for a USB drive is either because USB Flash drives are meant moreso to carry data and not programs, removing the barrier between OS's, and then because it's not too much of a hassle to carry two flash drives of two different colors.

As for burning a hybrid cd to a flash drive, it's very well possible, but your mileage *will* vary since from a driver level, both Windows and Mac will identify a USB flash drive as a flash drive regardless of the filesystem. You may get a U3 drive (which includes virtually all of Sandisk's drives) with [Universal Customizer](http://www.hak5.org/w/index.php/Universal_U3_LaunchPad_Hacker) ([alternate link](http://www.hak5.org/w/index.php/Universal_U3_LaunchPad_Hacker)) to put the hybrid iso into the fake CD partition. Only U3 drives have this ability; it's a part of their firmware/drive controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; Yeah i started out the NTFS/HFS+ route... made the NTFS partition hidden in OSX with 'SetFile -a V' - it works ok but isn't ideal, but may be my only real solution. That U3 sw looks very interesting; unfortunately i don't have the correct usb drive for it.

Comment: May I recommend this [$7 Cruzer](http://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-Cruzer-Micro-Flash-SDCZ6-4096-A11/dp/B000NWVAFO/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1284210018&sr=8-4)?